# Caffe installation Error on Windows 10

Tags: cmake, caffe

Hi I'm trying to install caffe framework by following steps on it's own  [github page](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows). 
When I execute "scripts\build_win.cmd". I got some errors:

> ..\libraries\bin\caffehdf5_D.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x330 [C:\Projects2\caf
>   fe\build\tools\upgrade_solver_proto_text.vcxproj]

Also when I look CMakeError.log:

> Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the
>   following output: Change Dir:
>   C:/Projects2/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_5c4c5.vcxproj"
>   "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0" Microsoft (R)
>   Build Engine version 12.0.31101.0
>
> [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Build started 26.12.2016 14:34:11.
>
> Project
>   "C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_5c4c5.vcxproj" on
>   node 1 (default targets).
>
> PrepareForBuild:
>
> Creating directory "cmTC_5c4c5.dir\Debug\".
>
> Creating directory
>   "C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".
>
> Creating directory "cmTC_5c4c5.dir\Debug\cmTC_5c4c5.tlog\".
>
> InitializeBuildStatus:
>
> Creating "cmTC_5c4c5.dir\Debug\cmTC_5c4c5.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild"
>   because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
>
> ClCompile:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1
>   /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope
>   /Fo"cmTC_5c4c5.dir\Debug\" /Fd"cmTC_5c4c5.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd
>   /TC /errorReport:queue
>   "C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c"
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D _DEBUG /D
>   "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise
>   /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTC_5c4c5.dir\Debug\"
>   /Fd"cmTC_5c4c5.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue
>   "C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c"
>
> CheckIncludeFile.c
>
> C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   [C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_5c4c5.vcxproj]
>
> Done Building Project
>   "C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_5c4c5.vcxproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_5c4c5.vcxproj"
>   (default target) (1) ->
>
> (ClCompile target) ->
>
> C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file
>   or directory
>   [C:\Projects2\caffe\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_5c4c5.vcxproj]
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
>
> 1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.34

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this error by changing folder permission to full access. reason is no read write permission.Link[1](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5840)